# convert a string to variable name for class attributes

Tags: python, class

I want to convert a string into variable name in class, but clearly it does not recognize "self." in the string.

I did a small trial with the following code, neither of vars(),locals(),globals() work.

```
class Myclass:
    def __init__(self):
        vars()[f'self.table{1}']=10
    def run(self):
        print(self.table1)

myclass = Myclass()
myclass.run()
```

The error is following:

```
File "/Users/Documents/Disentangle/test.py", line 8, in <module>
    myclass.run()
  File "/Users/zDocuments/Disentangle/test.py", line 5, in run
    print(self.table1)
AttributeError: 'Myclass' object has no attribute 'table1'
```

Comment: `vars(self)[f'table{1}'] = 10`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how to use `vars()` so I don't know how I could fix the error you're getting with it. However, I understand what you're trying to accomplish and I rewrote it using `setattr()`:

```py
class Myclass:
    def __init__(self):
        setattr(self, f'table{1}', 10)
    
    def run(self):
        print(self.table1)

myclass = Myclass()
myclass.run()
```

If you insist on using `vars()`, tell me and I'll research it and edit my answer. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt answer! This is exactly what I want. I use vars() or others simply because most tutorials use them.

Comment: Awesome! Make sure to mark the answer as accepted.